# Shorthanded if statement have errors

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I want to shorthand following if statement but my code editor shows that there are errors. What is the problem?

My original if statement

```
<?php
 if($shippingCost["ShippingCost"]['shipping_type'] == 'order_sum') {
    echo $this->Format->money($shippingCost["ShippingCost"]['value_to']);
 } else {
    echo number_format($shippingCost["ShippingCost"]['value_to']);
 }
?>
```

My shorthanded version

```
<?php
($shippingCost["ShippingCost"]['shipping_type'] == 'order_sum') ? //IDE error expected colon
echo $this->Format->money($shippingCost["ShippingCost"]['value_from']) : // IDE error expected semicolon
echo number_format($shippingCost["ShippingCost"]['value_from'])
?>
```

Comment: `echo a? a : b`

Comment: You really shouldn't write it that way. This looks terrible

Comment: You can read it in a manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php#refsect1-function.echo-examples but who looks at manual.

Comment: this is not a valid shorten code , if u want to go through it use echo ... but it wont work like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that `echo` doesn't have any return type. That's why you should either use print, or write echo in the beginning.

**1. Use echo in the beginning**

```
echo ($shippingCost["ShippingCost"]['shipping_type'] == 'order_sum') ? 
    $this->Format->money($shippingCost["ShippingCost"]['value_from']) : 
    number_format($shippingCost["ShippingCost"]['value_from']);
```

**2. Use print instead of echo**

```
($shippingCost["ShippingCost"]['shipping_type'] == 'order_sum') ? 

print $this->Format->money($shippingCost["ShippingCost"]['value_from']) :    
print number_format($shippingCost["ShippingCost"]['value_from']);
```

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator is a general-purpose shorthanded `if` statement, it's just a shorthanded way to return an expression. In this case, you could use the ternary on the expression only, and extract the `echo` out of it:

```
echo ($shippingCost["ShippingCost"]['shipping_type'] == 'order_sum') ?
      $this->Format->money($shippingCost["ShippingCost"]['value_from']) :
      number_format($shippingCost["ShippingCost"]['value_from']);
```